# Converting XML to PDF in Java

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

I need to convert  XML file to PDF using Java, is there any decent alternative to XSLT / anything to make the process of creating XSLT file less excruciating?.
Is there any way to get "live preview" instead of generating the file every time to check my changes?

Answer (score 1):

[ApacheFOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) could be of help! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023265/generating-pdf-from-xml-in-java-using-apachefop) out

Comment: This requires XSLT, which the OP asked for an alternative. Nevertheless, FOP is a great option.

Answer (score 0):

[Nimbus](http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus) is a free to use XSL designer based on html and css.
It allows you to create XSL for XSL FO applications.